# Question about Spring Data JDBC + Hikari + Postgres JSONB

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, hikaricp, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to build an API using Spring Boot Data JDBC with Postgres.

I have a simple pojo that I wish to write to a table:

```
public final class Test {
   private final String id;
   private final String definition;
}
```

The table has 2 columns, a varchar `id` column and a jsonb `definition` column.

When using a simple CRUD repository to save the pojo, I get the following error.

`ERROR: column "definition" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying`

The solution for this would normally be to pass `spring.datasourcehikari.connection-properties: stringtype=unspecified` in application.yml, but I can't get this to work.

When I activate the debug logging for hikari I can see other settings I activate for it (like the pool name)

```
HikariConfig testPool - configuration:
HikariConfig allowPoolSuspension.............false
HikariConfig autoCommit......................true
HikariConfig catalog.........................none
HikariConfig connectionInitSql...............none
HikariConfig connectionTestQuery.............none
HikariConfig connectionTimeout...............30000
HikariConfig dataSource......................none
HikariConfig dataSourceClassName.............none
HikariConfig dataSourceJNDI..................none
HikariConfig dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
HikariConfig driverClassName................."org.postgresql.Driver"
HikariConfig healthCheckProperties...........{}
HikariConfig healthCheckRegistry.............none
HikariConfig idleTimeout.....................600000
HikariConfig initializationFailTimeout.......1
HikariConfig isolateInternalQueries..........false
HikariConfig jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
HikariConfig leakDetectionThreshold..........0
HikariConfig maxLifetime.....................1800000
HikariConfig maximumPoolSize.................10
HikariConfig metricRegistry..................none
HikariConfig metricsTrackerFactory...........none
HikariConfig minimumIdle.....................10
HikariConfig password........................<masked>
HikariConfig poolName........................"testPool"
HikariConfig readOnly........................false
HikariConfig registerMbeans..................false
HikariConfig scheduledExecutor...............none
HikariConfig schema..........................none
HikariConfig threadFactory...................internal
HikariConfig transactionIsolation............default
HikariConfig username........................"test"
HikariConfig validationTimeout...............5000
HikariDataSource testPool - Starting...
HikariPool testPool - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@49ba49a7
HikariDataSource testPool - Start completed.
```

This is my application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
    username: test
    hikari:
      connection-properties: stringtype=unspecified
      poolName: testPool
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari: DEBUG
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

This is the repository interface:

```
@Repository
interface TestRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.<Test, String>{
}
```

Comment: Kindly please add the code of the repository used to map values from the database.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Thanks for the warning. I've added it.

Comment: you said you are using Spring Data JDBC but this looks like Spring Data JPA. What is the full qualified name of `CrudRepository` class?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki org.springframework.data.repository.CRUDRepository

Comment: @KarolDowbecki It works perfectly if I change the `jsonb` column to `text`

Comment: @JoaoNeto - What kind of json object you want to store in DB? Give the example json which you want to store in column "definition" (definition column is of type jsonb).

Comment: @JoaoNeto - 
I think you need to use
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties = stringtype=unspecified
in properties file.
And add "@Basic
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)" above getter of definition.

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks for the suggestion. The prop alone did the work. Can you put that in an answer so that I can accept? Thanks!

Comment: @JoaoNeto I have added as answer

Comment: You do not need a `@Repository` annotation on the repository interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you need to use data-source-properties in properties file as below**

spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties = stringtype=unspecified

**Then add two annotations above getter of "definition".**

@Basic
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public String getDefinition() {
     return definition;
}

Comment: Adding property `stringtype=unspecified` is enough to resolve the issue. The other two annotations are about enumeration type - different subject.