# How to read/write postgres jsonb type with spring-data-jdbc?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to use the following with spring-data-jdbc and postgres driver (kotlin),

```kotlin
data class MyEntity(
  val id: UUID,
  val content: String
)
```

using a string fails with the following error,

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "content" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 31
```

I'm not sure how I can use the converter for String -> jsonb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about Spring Data JDBC + Hikari + Postgres JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392146/question-about-spring-data-jdbc-hikari-postgres-jsonb)

Answer (score 9):

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35845278/810944) I implemented the following solution:

1. introduce a own class (POJO / kotlin data class) which holds the structure of the json-document (say `MyContent`)
2. implement a writing and a reading converter which converts the POJO into a String (say  with the help of `jackson`)
3. specifiy the postgres column type with the help of `org.postgresql.util.PGobject`

Details (only pseudo code):

```kotlin
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.data.convert.ReadingConverter
import org.springframework.data.convert.WritingConverter
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.postgresql.util.PGobject

@Table("my_entity")
data class MyEntity(
  @Id val id: UUID,
  val content: MyContent
) {

  @WritingConverter
  class EntityWritingConverter(
      private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
  ) : Converter<MyContent, PGobject> {
      override fun convert(source: MyContent): PGobject? {
          val jsonObject = PGobject()
          jsonObject.type = "json"
          jsonObject.value = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(source)
          return jsonObject
      }
  }

  @ReadingConverter
  class EntityReadingConverter(
      private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
  ) : Converter<PGobject, MyContent> {
      override fun convert(pgObject: PGobject): MyContent {
          val source = pgObject.value
          return objectMapper.readValue<MyContent>(source)
      }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add the two converters to `spring-data-jdbc`s configuration (see `JdbcCustomConversions`).

This works with this corresponding postgres table:

```sql
create table if not exists my_entity
(
    id uuid not null primary key,
    content jsonb
);
```

Comment: In my case this solution does not work. Spring treats custom POJO as related entity and makes query with `JOIN my_content ...`. I did everything according to your advice, registered custom converter as it's described in Spring docs and still this does not work. Maybe you have any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: For the record. It is important to have both `@ReadingConverter` and `@WritingConverter` to make spring-data-jbdc treat `MyContent` as simple type. Otherwise sping-data will generate SQL with `JOIN my_content` part. More than that, in fact, only `@WritingConverter` counts, as inside spring-data it is used for registration of custom simple types.

Comment: @RomanMitasov, how have you actually made spring-data-jdbc treat an entity as a simple type?

Comment: @Kirill registering `@WritingConverter` for entity type makes spring-data-jdbc treat that type as simple. I've mentioned that in previous comment.

Comment: Thanks, @RomanMitasov, you're correct. My problem turned out to be different: as soon as you try to use in an auto-generated repository method a field from an object that is stored as JSONB, spring-data-jdbc seems to be refusing to consider this object a simple type anymore. Otherwise what you've written above works nice.
I wasn't able to "fix" this, so I resorted to custom queries.