# I don't understand how to save an entity to the database using jsonb and Spring Data JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jsonb, spring-data-jdbc

I have an entity in my Spring Boot application:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "my_files")
public class myFile {

@Id private Long id;

private String content;
}
```

Here is the table that corresponds to this entity:

```
create table if not exists my_files

(
id bigint not null primary key,
content jsonb
);
```

The problem is that when I try to put the entity into the database, the following error occurs:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "file_data" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I understand that I need to convert a string to jsonb. I found several guides on how to do this for Hibernate, but I am using Spring Data JDBC in my project and can't figure out how to solve this problem. Please help me find a solution.

I tried to find a solution, but they are all applicable to Hibernate.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64521056/1915448) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53392146/1915448)? Those are about Spring Data JDBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL and Hikari datasource pool add this property:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties=stringtype=unspecified
```

The property is for PostgreSQL only.

I understand that you want to do it with JDBC only. But - just for the record - let me show how easy it would be with Hibernate (part of Spring Boot Data JPA).

Add this annotation to the field definition in the entity:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;
// ...
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private String content;
```

This would work with any database with JSON data type (like PostgreSQL, H2, Oracle, MySQL).

Please note: `content` need to be a valid JSON String representation. For example:

```java
    content = "{}"
```

Comment: I understand that using Hibernate would make this easy, but unfortunately, I simply have no choice...

Comment: Please try out the solution with property `stringtype=unspecified`. This is a valid workaround. Let us know if it works.

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! Please tell me, am I right in understanding that this applies to all fields in the database that are of the jsonb type? Can you also explain how this works?

Comment: Yes, all fields of json and/or json type. This is because in Postgres the default type for String is varchar. Setting it to `unspecified` cause the driver to check the actual type and use it for conversion instead.

Comment: Please accept my answer. It will mark the issue as resolved.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thank you very much again for your help!

Comment: Good day, but now I have another problem related to the issue that, when I retrieve an entity from the database, an error occurs:

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.postgresql.util.PGobject] to type [java.lang.String]